# Pass session variable as Key-Value pair to PHP file using AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session-variables

I have a session variable, say $_SESSION['Current_User']. I want to pass it to a URL as a key-value pair using AJAX. I have some HTML inputs as follows:
HTML is:

```
<INPUT type='text' name='input_1' id="INPUT_1"></INPUT>
<INPUT type='text' name='input_2' id="INPUT_2"></INPUT>
<INPUT type='text' name='input_3' id="INPUT_3"></INPUT>
<BUTTON id="BUTTON_1" name="BUTTON_1_SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT_1" onclick="ajax_post()">Post</BUTTON>

<DIV id="Sub_Div_4"></DIV>
```

Javascript is:

```
function ajax_post()   
    {   var AJAX = new ajaxFunction();
        AJAX.onreadystatechange = function()
        {   if((AJAX.readyState == 4) && (AJAX.status == 200))
                {   var PHP_REPLY = AJAX.responseText; 
                var RECI_EVE_D = JSON.parse(PHP_REPLY);     
                var STRING_jsonified = "|||data_1: " + RECI_EVE_D.data_1 + "||| data_2: " + RECI_EVE_D.data_2+ "||| data_3: "  + RECI_EVE_D.data_3;
                document.getElementById("Sub_Div_4").innerHTML = STRING_jsonified;
        }       }
    var INP_1 = document.getElementById("INPUT_1").value;
    var INP_2 = document.getElementById("INPUT_2").value;
    var INP_3 = document.getElementById("INPUT_3").value;
    
    var PARAM = "input_1=" + INP_1 + "&input_2=" + INP_2 + "&input_3=" + INP_3 ; 
    AJAX.open("POST", "PHP/PHP_SIMPLE_AJAX_POST.PHP", true);  
    AJAX.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    AJAX.send(PARAM);
    }
```

Lets say, the PHP file PHP_SIMPLE_AJAX_POST.PHP needs that session information, and the user inputs to do some processing and send back JSON. So my question is, how do I package the existing $_SESSION['Current_user'] and send it to the PHP file?
Thanks, much appreciated!!

Comment: You seem to be thinking about this backwards. The $_SESSION exists server side, not in client. When the ajax request comes in start the session and access it as you would with a any other request

Comment: you mean to say that in the PHP file 
 in the URL, i.e. PHP_SIMPLE_AJAX_POST.PHP, if I have a "session_start()" at the top of that file, I will be able to access the session variable?

Comment: Yes...exactly...

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. And also, if I might ask.. what if I have some existing POST variables like $_POST['var1'] on the current HTML file, how do I pass them onto the PHP file.. is there a way?

Comment: charlie, thanks for your advise, let me try what you suggested re. the session_start!

Comment: That's not as clear cut.$_POST variables only exist for a single request. Somewhat depends what you are trying to do. using session is one possibility

Comment: Ah okay, meaning I could assign $_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['a'] and so on.. and then get them in the php file. I also heard of hidden inputs with value assigned with php echo $_post['a'], wonder if that would result in security issues.

Comment: As far as hidden inputs are concerned, depends how sensitive the data is. As for `$_SESSION['a'] = $_POST['a']` ... yes can certainly do that. Don't want to bloat the session with too much stuff and there is also something known as flash session that only exists for next request and then is gone

Comment: ah okay. I will check out all the methods you told me. Thank you so much charlie, so much appreciated!!

Comment: am a bit of a newbie so will have to research a bit on flash sessions.  Just doing basic php and javascript etc.. lol. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, how to use the value of any currently existing `$_SESSION` values, you could try this:

```
<INPUT type='text' name='input_1' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Current_user']['input_1']; ?>" id="INPUT_1"></INPUT>
<INPUT type='text' name='input_2' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Current_user']['input_2']; ?>" id="INPUT_2"></INPUT>
<INPUT type='text' name='input_3' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Current_user']['input_3']; ?>" id="INPUT_3"></INPUT>
```

**Update**

Then you should manipulate the `$_POST` value in your PHP script as such:

```
$_SESSION['Current_user']['input_1'] = $_POST['input_1'];
$_SESSION['Current_user']['input_2'] = $_POST['input_2'];
$_SESSION['Current_user']['input_3'] = $_POST['input_3'];
```

Comment: Hi Cyril, thanks. But what if I want to keep the session variable hidden? and I want to actually obtain the value of input_1,2,3 from the user

Comment: Thank you Cyril, let me go and try it out... thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @Madventures. Great! if it works out, please accept the answer :)